# Does an outdoor PoE Access Point need seperate grounding?

Tags: grounding, wifi, poe

I've searched high and low for an definitive answer on this, including speaking with electricians, but still get conflicting opinions on this.

The goal:
Install an outdoor wifi access point (AP), powered via PoE. *(Specifically a Unifi UAP-AC-M-PRO)*

Initial plan would be to just connect it like so:

```
      INDOORS | OUTDOORS
[ Switch ] ----------------- cat6 w/ PoE------------------- [ Access Point ]
              |
```

With the cat6 cable being rated for direct burial, and buried 18" down, directly or in conduit.
And the AP mounted on a pole or tree.

However, Unifi's [own instructions recommend](https://dl.ubnt.com/qsg/UAP-AC-M-PRO/UAP-AC-M-PRO_EN.html) having two surge protectors (labeled SP1 and SP2 below) *(Specifically their ETH-SP-G2 model)*
One at where it enters the building. And another at the AP:

```
      INDOORS | OUTDOORS
[ Switch ] -----[SP1]------------ cat6 w/ PoE-------------------[SP2]--[ Access Point ]
              |
```

However, they don't specify what to ground these to.
I would assume SP1 would ground to the building's ground, into an outlet box.
But what would SP2 would ground to? The pole? A grounding rod?

As I've researched this, I find again and again warnings not to add an extra grounding rod, because it can create a new pathway for nearby lightning strikes to travel into the building,
on its way over to the building's ground, passing through the networking equipment along the way.

So then that leads me to consider this option:

```
      INDOORS | OUTDOORS
[ Switch ] -----[SP]------------ cat6 w/ PoE--------------------[ Access Point ]
              |
```

Where I only do one surge protector, and do not attempt to add a new grounding rod.
And possibly add a ethernet lightning suppressor before the switch.

Ultimately, I'd like to install this outside, but getting conflicting info on the best practices for this install. Hoping to get some clearer answers. Thanks

Comment: A link to the document referring to the placement of SPs is needed. All we have at the moment is your interpretation so, there can be no answer to the question as it currently stands.

Comment: Isn't this still a question of what modules to buy and how to use them? Sounds like a networking/IT question as they may know the specifics of lightning safety rules of these more better than electricians. Of course local electrical code must be obeyed, wherever you are located.

Comment: @Andyaka updated question to have a link to their instructions, but also linking here https://dl.ubnt.com/qsg/UAP-AC-M-PRO/UAP-AC-M-PRO_EN.html cheers

Comment: I'm curious where you found the warning "not to add an extra grounding rod, because it can create a new pathway for nearby lightning strikes to travel into the building".  The only other way to ground SP2 would be by a dedicated ground wire *directly into the building*.

Comment: *I find again and again warnings not to add an extra grounding rod* <-- please indicate where this came from.

Comment: My house was struck directly by lighting, and my opinion is that while a grounding rod probably won't save your electronic devices from damage caused by a full lighting strike, it still might save your house from a fire caused by arcing from external cabling that enters the house. There should be a grounding rod at the extremity of any external cabling.